# logger4j IsTracingEnabled

Tags: java, grails, trace

Getting this Grails error in IntelliJ, never seen it before.  I am running Grails 2.2.1

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z
at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.isTraceEnabled(GrailsLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.isTraceEnabled(SLF4JLog.java:86)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:230)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:220)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:975)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:62)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy:69)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:61)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:58)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:45)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:42)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:41)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:30)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
| Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z
```

Any thoughts on what this is from?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that Groovy is binding it's own slf4j-log4j bridge to `Spring`'s slf4j logging framework and that is calling a method on the version of log4j in your classpath that doesn't exist.

According to [this](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/slf4j-dev/2007-December/001238.html) the method it wants to call, `org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()`, wasn't added until version 1.2.12 of log4j so make sure the version you have in the classpath is that or newer.

Comment: Great, not really sure where the classpath is stored though

Comment: Take at look at [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#ivy), should help.

Comment: From the [pom](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.pom) Spring has a compile time dependency on log4j that is optional - so the jar probably doesn't come from there. There should be some way to view your dependency graph and see what's what. Maybe try manually including the newer version of log4j into your dependencies.

Comment: Had log4j 1.2.9 and that was the problem , so thanks for the tip about the version.